# PHP comparing from CSV and user input

Tags: php

I am writing a small script that when the user inputs their ID number, it will verify against an external csv file to check if the user exists.

```
$errortext=' ';

$sfile = fopen("compch.csv","r");
    rewind($sfile);
    while (!feof($sfile)) {
    $data2 = fgets($sfile);
    $splitter2 = explode("|", $data2);

  if(!in_array($reference,$splitter2))
  {
    $errortext = "Invalid proposal number"; 
     return $errortext; 
  }

 }
```

Problem with this code is that if the first ID is not the users ID, the loop will be broken instead of the next entry being read. 
Is there a way to edit the loop so that it keeps reading the ID's and if the current users ID does not exist, then only show the error message?

Comment: You can use continue; in a loop... this will skip the record and continue to the next one... simply check if the ID is not there. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: I actually did that too. However, it's the same results as below. It rejects all entries or accepts all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a break if you find the right element, otherwise you continue :

```
$errortext = ' ';
$bool = false;
$sfile = fopen("compch.csv","r");
    rewind($sfile);
    while (!feof($sfile)) {
    $data2 = fgets($sfile);
    $splitter2 = explode("|", $data2);

  if(in_array($reference,$splitter2))
  {
    $bool = true;
    break; //YOu exit the while loop
  }

 }//End of while loop
 if ($bool){
  //ID is inside
 }else{
   $errortext = "Invalid proposal number"; 
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried that and it rejected everything with the message "Invalid proposal number"
My data is structured like this if it helps
User1|100000
User2|100001
Theres a linebreak between the 2 data.

Comment: it's maybe because you have a breakline between each data: a breakline is a char '\n' and it could disturb the behavior of your code: explode('|',$data2) = explode('|','User1|100000\n') = array(0=>'User1',1=>'100000\n') and '100000\n' != '100000'. Try to add a separator after the ID for each line